# NPM delivered package.json throws error

Tags: json, node.js, npm, package, bower

I have created an NPM package and installed it to test it. NPM/Node throws an ENOENT error when installing dependencies for GruntJS in a nested node_modules folder with `npm install`.

I take these steps to create the error:

- `npm install pavilion`
- `cd node_modules/pavilion`
- `npm install`

When installing the dependencies for Grunt, listed in the package.json...it throws the error as seen below.
PS. please continue reading below.

```
npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v5.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6
npm ERR! path /Users/Baasdesign/Desktop/test/node_modules/pavilion/node_modules/.staging/pavilion-8a19d0be
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/Users/Baasdesign/Desktop/test/node_modules/pavilion/node_modules/.staging/pavilion-8a19d0be' -> '/Users/Baasdesign/Desktop/test/node_modules/pavilion'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/Users/Baasdesign/Desktop/test/node_modules/pavilion/node_modules/.staging/pavilion-8a19d0be' -> '/Users/Baasdesign/Desktop/test/node_modules/pavilion'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v5.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6
npm ERR! path npm-debug.log.575049388
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'npm-debug.log.575049388'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'npm-debug.log.575049388'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/Baasdesign/Desktop/test/node_modules/pavilion/npm-debug.log
```

Now the weird part. When I use Bower to install the package...I don't get the error. Here are my steps:

- `bower install pavilion`
- `cd bower_components/pavilion`
- `npm install`

Everything installs fine. The difference? ---> *the package.json.*
The bower install package.json works find. NPM's doesn't.

Bower gives me a clean package.json, as created by myself before publishing to npm.
NPM install gives me an package.json that had a lot more info in there. When I use the bower package.json...everything install fine...even when I paste and replace the npm package.json in the node_modules folder.

What's the deal here? It seems that the package.json delivered with the npm install messes up the dependency installation.

Here is the bower package.json delivery: 
http://pastebin.com/g8FgSDNG

And here is the npm package.json delivery:
http://pastebin.com/xTiQ15ih

I have tried `npm cache clean` but it didn't work.

sysinfo:

- OSX Yosemite
- node - 5.10.1
- npm - 3.8.6

Comment: NPM is sometimes a pain as the error messages dont normally give you much.. have you tried a simple package.json and tried to install it and worked from there? I always work down from simple to complex to diagnose the issue

Comment: Yeah. the package.json that comes with the bower installation is much simpler, and that works fine! But I need it to work in NPM too :(

Answer (score 1):

Node is brilliant but can be a pain sometimes!

I have had this error myself lately and for me rolling back to an earlier version of node fixed my problem.

I would recommend you try out an earlier install you could use "node version manager" to have a few node versions on your system and it provides methods to switch between versions.

I know its not a very technical answer and i hope someone has a specific answer to your question!

[https://github.com/creationix/nvm]

Here's the version manager link hope it helps

Comment: Thanks will try it. But it's not really efficient like this right?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I didn't save the dependency in the package.json.
I guess Node gets the paths wrong if you do that.

So the correct workflow is:

- `npm init` (create the package.json)
- `npm install <package> --save-dev`
- `cd node_modules/pavilion`
- `npm install`

Then it works fine. The `<package>` needs to be added to the parent directory's package.json.